# How do i configure SDL to work with the Blackberry Playbook Native SDK / NDK?

Tags: sdl, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I've got the NDK set up and managed to compile and run the hello native sdk project on my playbook. I downloaded the blackberry sdl port from github. However I've been unable to compile even a hello world project using it. Also it seems to be lacking a "lib" folder which I'm used to needing for the compiler settings.

EDIT: I have managed to get the sdl to open in the native sdk, it seems the download was designed to act as a project template of sorts. At first the compiler complained that i needed another library, TouchControlOverlay. So I downloaded this and set up the includes to include it. However again I couldn't find a lib folder, and the project still wont compile, saying it cannot find -lTouchControlOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the compile cannot find TouchControlOverlay is because it's not installed on your host machine. To install it:

1. Clone TouchControlOverlay from here: https://github.com/blackberry/TouchControlOverlay
2. Go into the directory and run:

   make && make install

If you now navigate to: `$QNX_TARGET/armle-v7/lib` you should see that `libTouchControlOverlay.so` has been placed there. You should now be able to link against this library using `-lTouchControlOverlay`

Note that you will need to package this library with your application by specifying it as an `<asset>` in your `bar-descriptor.xml` file.