# How to setup SDL with NDK / Native of Blackberry OS 10?

Tags: sdl, blackberry-10

I have a Mac enviroment with snow leopard and I Would like to port a written game with sdl to bb10.
My enviroment works with cascades and opengl samples...

I saw there is an SDL port on github.com/blackberry and a TouchoverlayLibrary to use..but I don't know how to create and setup SDL in momentics and create a new SDL project with momentics.

For now I did these steps:

- gitclone sdl blackberry port
- gitclone touchoverlaylibrary

But now I'm stucked ... cause I don't know how to move...

I suppose that I have to compile the 2 library .. but how? 
Should I use momentics or what else?
..any help?

P.S: This solution didn't helped me: [How do i configure SDL to work with the Blackberry Playbook Native SDK / NDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289628/how-do-i-configure-sdl-to-work-with-the-blackberry-playbook-native-sdk-ndk)

Answer (score 2):

OK after some research and a lot of test... I found a workaround... here is a little guide:
http://pestohacks.blogspot.it/2012/12/simple-setup-sdl-on-blackberry-os-10-on.html